# setgid sticky bit not working

Tags: permissions, acl, rsyslog, setgid

I have yet another frustrating problem. I have a group of users belonging to the "testing" group. I have a folder located at /var/log/projects with the setgid bit set. This is so any new files or folders that get created in /projects will always retain the group ownership of "testing".

```
[root@system log]# ll | grep projects
drwxr-s---. 4 root   testing     4096 Jun 10 19:36 projects
```

When I touch a file or create a folder in that directory they inherit the correct perms and ownership.

```
[root@system log]# touch /var/log/projects/testfile
[root@system log]# ll /var/log/projects/
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root testing    0 Jun 10 19:49 testfile
```

And when I create a new folder its works as expected.

```
[root@system projects]# mkdir folder1
[root@system projects]# ll
total 8
drwxr-sr-x. 2 root testing 4096 Jun 10 19:52 folder1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root testing    0 Jun 10 19:49 testfile
```

So far so good. However I am using this folder for remote syslogs from other systems. When I start the rsyslogd service, any folders of files created by that process inherit the ownership of root:root.

```
drwx--S---. 2 root root 4096 Jun 10 19:44 remotehost
```

I was under the impression that the purpose of the setgid bit was for my use case. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how I can fix this so that any folders/files created by the rsyslogd process have the group ownership of "testing"? This is on a RHEL 6 server.

Comment: After the title, you do not mention the sticky bit again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since rsyslog ignores setgid sticky bits I was able to correct the issue by using the following directives in my rsyslogd.conf custom template config:

```
$template TmplAuth, "/var/log/projects/%FROMHOST-IP%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
$template TmplMsg, "/var/log/projects/%FROMHOST-IP%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
$umask 0000
$DirCreateMode 0750
$FileCreateMode 0640
$FileGroup testing
$DirGroup testing
authpriv.*   ?TmplAuth
*.info,mail.none,authpriv.none,cron.none   ?TmplMsg
```

NOTE $DirCreateMode and $FileCreateMode will not work until you override the default umask with the $umask 0000 directive.

Answer (score 4):

The method you made would work with programs that don't specifically manage their output permissions and ownership, but rsyslogd does.

[`Rsyslogd`'s output module documentation page](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfile.html) shows that you can use the `fileGroup [groupName]` configuration directive to set the default value for the output file's group.

Comment: Thanks but I am going to post a more descriptive answer that helps with rsyslog config. I did up-vote you however.